# RemoteFX GPU not appearing in Add Hardware for HyperV

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012, remote-desktop

I'm trying a PoC for RemoteFX and am having issues adding a 'RemoteFX Video Adapter' to my Win8 Enterprise VM.  I'm working on section four of [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx) and just don't have the option to add the video adapter to the guest.  HyperV sees the card and acknowledges that I can use it.  I have verified I'm running Windows 8 Enterprise in the VM.

I'm running Server 2012 R2 DataCenter with the HyperV role and the card is a Quadro 2000.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was I was trying to use a Gen2 VM instead of a Gen1.  Creating a new VM based on Gen1 "hardware" fixed the issue.